# I get dependency not found when I try to install a local vue js library I created to my app using yarn add ../library

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, yarnpkg

I created a library in Vue using this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@olivierpicault/create-a-vue-js-component-library-as-a-module-part-1-a1116e632751) and the library works as expected. But problem comes I install this library and import the module into Vue project I created using `yarn add ../vue-okra`

and I import it into the my existing vue file as: `import OkraButton from 'vue-okra'` see the full snippet below:

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import OkraButton from 'vue-okra'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

when I run a yarn serve on this project to see if the library works in this project, I get the error:

```
> This dependency was not found: * vue-okra in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

i saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252654/this-dependency-was-not-found-typescript-vue) but it does not seem to be much help. Please, what am I doing wrong?

---

Comment: Is vue-okra in the same directory as you app.js?

Comment: @funkysoul no I added it as a dependency using yarn add ../vue-okra

Comment: are you trying to import {OkraButton } (deconstruct) vs OkraButton  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install package with local path by Yarn? It couldn't find package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102686/how-to-install-package-with-local-path-by-yarn-it-couldnt-find-package)

Comment: yes it does, thank you