# TypeScript: import from custom d.ts file

Tags: typescript, module, dependencies, .d.ts

I've created a `foo.t.ds` in `src/types/`, which describes the types of my project:

```
export namespace foo {
    // some interfaces and class definitions
}
```

I don't have any problem to import in my project; however, when compiling, I get:

```
This dependency was not found:

* @/types/foo in ./src/directory/file.ts

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/types/foo
```

Somebody has any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have a config file inside your project? I think its global config for all your project to import files should be done

Comment: Yes, I have got a `tsconfig.json` file. Where should I specify this file?

Comment: Are you working with Vue js cli ?

Comment: Yes, right. Why?

Comment: did you check this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252654/this-dependency-was-not-found-typescript-vue

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, when I'm modifying `import { foo } from @/types/foo` to `import { foo } from ../../types/foo` and then running, I get:
`This relative module was not found:

* ../../foo in ./src/directory/file.ts`

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Comment: Not yet, do you think it's a correct way to declare custom classes and interfaces inside a `d.ts` file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216496/discussion-between-bastian-nanchen-and-rebai-ahmed).